# How to show tooltips inside a ScrollPane without letting Flash 8 hide the tooltip?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, scrollpane

I have the content of a scrollpane that, when clicked, show a tooltip movieclip with attachMovieClip; the problem is that the attached movie clip, for the first rows, goes under the border of the ScrollPane and is partially invisible.
Is there a way to solve this problem (without changing the position of the attached movie clip?)

Comment: Have you tried passing getNextHighestDepth() as the third parameter of attachMovie()? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001303.html . The following are worth a look too: http://help.adobe.com/it_IT/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00002309.html and http://goflashgo.wordpress.com/2007/04/19/simple-depth-manager/

Comment: Please give a bit of code that shows what is being done.  Is this exclusively in AS3 (FlashBuilder, etc.) or is it in the Flash IDE?  By "changing position", does this mean x,y or does it mean depth level in the object stack?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are loading a movieclip inside the `ScrollPane`'s `contentPath`.  This movieclip dynamically loads *another* movieclip, the tooltip.  If you are loading the tooltip this way, the depth doesn't matter: everything within the `ScrollPane` object is clipped, and you will never be able to view what is underneath.  This is the whole point of a `ScrollPane` class, of course; it shows only a bit of the underlying content at a time, and allows the user to scroll around.

Here is code that can replicate the problem:

```
this.attachMovie("tooltip1","tooltip1A", 100); //note the high level     
var mouseListener:Object = new Object();
mouseListener.onMouseMove = function() {
    tooltip1A._x = _xmouse;
    tooltip1A._y = _ymouse;
    updateAfterEvent();
};

Mouse.addListener(mouseListener);
```

Put this inside a library movieclip (call it `paneContentMC`).  Open the Properties.  Check "Export for Actionscript" and make the "Identifier:" text "paneContentMC1".  Close the Properties, and then create some random graphics on the timeline in `paneContentMC`.

Create another movieclip called `tooltip`.  Open the Properties.  Check "Export for Actionscript" and make the "Identifier:" text "tooltip1".

Finally, on the scene's main timeline, create a `ScrollPane` and make the "contentPath" property "paneContentMC1".  Put a `stop();` command in the Actionscript for the first frame of this timeline.

There you have a clipped tooltip.  How do you fix this?

You need to make the tooltip attach to an object outside the `ScrollPane`'s content.  Since you do not know what objects may or may not exist on the stage at runtime, pick a global object, like `_root`.

Go into the Actionscript inside `paneContentMC`.  Change the code to:

```
var mc1:MovieClip = _root.attachMovie("tooltip1","tooltip1A", _root.getNextHighestDepth());

var mouseListener:Object = new Object();
mouseListener.onMouseMove = function() {
    _root.tooltip1A._x = _xmouse;
    _root.tooltip1A._y = _ymouse;
    updateAfterEvent();
};
```

This does not solve the problem entirely, since `tooltip1A` is following the mouse around outside the `ScrollPane`.  But if the `tooltip1A` is listening for movement events from the `paneContentMC` rather than from the mouse, this should work out.

(Edited to fix a voting error.)

Comment: Good to know.  Thanks for the upvote (which I assume was you)!

Comment: @iND: iND, sorry, it was my fault: I wanted to upvote your rich reply but I downvoted... If you edit a little your reply it seems I can upvote.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the comment.  I edited it, so see if anything changes.